# Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

This seems to be a new error for previously well running code. Probably user error...

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
transactionDate
2022-08-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
2021-09-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
2022-08-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
2022-03-01T00:00:00.000-05:00
2021-08-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
2022-08-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
2022-03-01T00:00:00.000-05:00
2021-08-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
2021-11-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
2022-03-01T00:00:00.000-05:00
2021-12-01T00:00:00.000-05:00
"""))

dates = pd.to_datetime(df.transactionDate)

dates.apply(type)
```

```
0     <class 'datetime.datetime'>
1     <class 'datetime.datetime'>
2     <class 'datetime.datetime'>
3     <class 'datetime.datetime'>
4     <class 'datetime.datetime'>
5     <class 'datetime.datetime'>
6     <class 'datetime.datetime'>
7     <class 'datetime.datetime'>
8     <class 'datetime.datetime'>
9     <class 'datetime.datetime'>
10    <class 'datetime.datetime'>
Name: transactionDate, dtype: object
```

```py
dates.transactionDate.dt.date
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/52/cz8ms60j73x2mdzq9kjknqzh0000gp/T/ipykernel_14842/1511363732.py in <module>
----> 1 dates.transactionDate.dt.date

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5573         ):
   5574             return self[name]
-> 5575         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5576 
   5577     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/accessor.py in __get__(self, obj, cls)
    180             # we're accessing the attribute of the class, i.e., Dataset.geo
    181             return self._accessor
--> 182         accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
    183         # Replace the property with the accessor object. Inspired by:
    184         # https://www.pydanny.com/cached-property.html

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/accessors.py in __new__(cls, data)
    507             return PeriodProperties(data, orig)
    508 
--> 509         raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")

AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Comment: if you run what you wrote here, *"Series" object has no attribute "transactionDate"* is seen.

Comment: Converting `.to_datetime` with the `utc=True` kwarg works: `dates = pd.to_datetime(df.transactionDate, utc=True); dates.dt.date`.  The timezone at the end of the datetime values needed to be accounted for, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed UTC offsets. `pandas` cannot handle this with the built-in datetime type (pd.Timestamp), so it falls back to vanilla Python datetime. Therefore no `dt` accessor.

If you want to have the dt accessor here, you can parse to UTC:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
transactionDate
2022-08-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
2021-09-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
2022-08-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
2022-03-01T00:00:00.000-05:00
2021-08-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
2022-08-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
2022-03-01T00:00:00.000-05:00
2021-08-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
2021-11-01T00:00:00.000-04:00
2022-03-01T00:00:00.000-05:00
2021-12-01T00:00:00.000-05:00
"""))

df["dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df.transactionDate, utc=True)
print(df["dates"].head(4))
# 0   2022-08-01 04:00:00+00:00
# 1   2021-09-01 04:00:00+00:00
# 2   2022-08-01 04:00:00+00:00
# 3   2022-03-01 05:00:00+00:00
# Name: dates, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

If you want to get the original timezone back, convert from UTC:

```py
df["dates"] = df["dates"].dt.tz_convert("America/New_York")
print(df["dates"].head(4))
# 0   2022-08-01 00:00:00-04:00
# 1   2021-09-01 00:00:00-04:00
# 2   2022-08-01 00:00:00-04:00
# 3   2022-03-01 00:00:00-05:00
# Name: dates, dtype: datetime64[ns, America/New_York]
```